# What ID is sent to Exchange ActiveSync from Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, activesync

When my WP7 phone connects to my EAS server I can see among other things it's Device ID (B5B0EA77FE982C6EB38584985E98F221). 
This ID does not match with anything I can get from the device via API.
Using DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueId) gives me something totally different.
Does anyone know if there is possibility to get the same ID also from some API call?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but since that ID is the exact same length as a UUID I'm going to guess that the EAS client on Windows Phone 7 simply generates one randomly (or salts it with some device-specific info) and stores it for re-use in all EAS sessions going forward.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. Why couldn't they just use the existing DeviceUniqueID which is there for just this purpose and would allow others to link EAS with 3rd party solutions

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered checking whether it's perhaps your UUID on the Exchange server?

Comment: It most probably is. But I need to get the same value in my phone application without connecting anywere.